# Post request working in Postman but not in php code(SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL)

Tags: php, curl, post, request, postman

I'm trying to make a simple curl post request using PHP code snippet from Postman. But when I'm trying to run it I get the following error: "OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054"

In postman the request is working fine and I do get the json results. 
Here's an inline link for postman header [image: Postman Header]

and the postman body [image: Postman body]

My php code is the following:

```php
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.oglasnik.hr/ajax/getNearBy",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 500,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"classifiedId\"\r\n\r\n3996266\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"bounds\"\r\n\r\n{\"east\":16.00793838500977,\"west\":15.977039337158205,\"north\":45.78652940999985,\"south\":45.773958941535355}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
                "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
                "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9",
                "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                "Connection: keep-alive",
                "Content-Length: 384",
                "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Cookie: cookieconsent_status=allow; ogl_visits^[0^]=a5cbwGRWU7YEC1LP6tKOVOzf6GIZzyU7dbry64BfNak4xygExIAj^%^2FkGWQ5azKqmznEHJVCF4ZfufdAaCugfPjPi8vX7CB8Gs^%^2F3OdX5RVvYjyfWKHUHboChkYfbURk6Ly",
                "Host: www.oglasnik.hr",
                "Origin: https://www.oglasnik.hr",
                "Postman-Token: 60eebbd3-ed26-4aed-ae32-f190353ce333,aa32ad1d-55c6-4fa6-928e-3309a497c36a",
                "Referer: https://www.oglasnik.hr/stanovi-najam/novi-zagreb-bundek-2-sobni-stan-55-m2-oglas-3996266",
                "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36",
                "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",
                "cache-control: no-cache",
                "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            echo $response;
        }
```

**UPDATE**:

With the tip from @Andrew I changed the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER to:

```php
 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
              "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
              "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
              "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9",
              "Cache-Control: no-cache",
              "Connection: keep-alive",
              "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
              "Cookie: cookieconsent_status=allow; ogl_visits^[0^]=a5cbwGRWU7YEC1LP6tKOVOzf6GIZzyU7dbry64BfNak4xygExIAj^%^2FkGWQ5azKqmznEHJVCF4ZfufdAaCugfPjPi8vX7CB8Gs^%^2F3OdX5RVvYjyfWKHUHboChkYfbURk6Ly",
              "Host: www.oglasnik.hr",
              "Origin: https://www.oglasnik.hr",
              "Referer: https://www.oglasnik.hr/stanovi-najam/novi-zagreb-bundek-2-sobni-stan-55-m2-oglas-3996266",
              "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36",
              "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",
              "cache-control: no-cache",
              "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
            )
```

And i'm getting the response! Unfortunately its only

```
{
    "status": false
}
```

As it looks like I'm sending my post parameters wrong. Problem is that I need to send one integer parameter and one string as json, currently trying like this:

```php
 $bounds = 
  [
     "east" => 16.00793838500977,
      "west" =>15.977039337158205,
      "north" =>45.78652940999985,
      "south" =>45.773958941535355
  ];


  $params = [
      "classifiedId" => 3996266, "bounds"  => json_encode($bounds)
   ];
```

and adding this parameter in curl_setopt_array:

```php
 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params
```

**Final update:**

It worked! As @Andrew stated in the comments it worked using:

```php
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($params)
```

so the final header is:

```php
 curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.oglasnik.hr/ajax/getNearBy",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($params),
            CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT =>  true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
              "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
              "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
              "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9",
              "Cache-Control: no-cache",
              "Connection: keep-alive",
              "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
              "Cookie: cookieconsent_status=allow; ogl_visits^[0^]=a5cbwGRWU7YEC1LP6tKOVOzf6GIZzyU7dbry64BfNak4xygExIAj^%^2FkGWQ5azKqmznEHJVCF4ZfufdAaCugfPjPi8vX7CB8Gs^%^2F3OdX5RVvYjyfWKHUHboChkYfbURk6Ly",
              "Host: www.oglasnik.hr",
              "Origin: https://www.oglasnik.hr",
              "Referer: https://www.oglasnik.hr/stanovi-najam/novi-zagreb-bundek-2-sobni-stan-55-m2-oglas-3996266",
              "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36",
              "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",
              "cache-control: no-cache",
              "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
            ),
          ));
```

Comment: Are you using Vagrant by any chance? Or any other similar tool we should know about?

Comment: + try removing the entire "CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER" section. That is Postman's stuff in there, it's not necessary in PHP. I'm getting a timeout with that included, but no error without it (no response though, either).

Comment: @Andrew my project is using symfony local server with xampp. will try your advice and reply with the results.

Comment: ty @Andrew, it did solve the strange ssl error. Now I'm not getting any result probably because I'm sending parameter  in POST_FILEDS with json data wrong. {"east":16.00793838500977,"west":15.977039337158205,"north":45.78652940999985,"south":45.773958941535355}

Comment: updated the original question with newest results.

Comment: Sorry mate, no matter what I try, the response-code is always 400. One thing I'm sure of is that you should use  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($params) ... Also I noticed the cookie-field in Postman. Maybe you did some kind of login authorization if Postman first, and since then, it carries your user-cookie that validates your request? Otherwise the server just responds with a 400 error (which can mean anything, but supposedly it's a client-side issue). It's hard to say exactly without knowing what's going on in the getNearBy method.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the results using http_build_query. :)